# How to restore Cassandra shapshot after changing number of nodes in the cluster

Tags: cassandra, restore

Let's assume we had the 3-node cluster with the following nodes: node1, node2, node3.
One day we created a snapshot for entire cluster and copied snapshot tables from each node to external backup server.

Some time has passed and now the cluster is grown: instead of 3 nodes we have 5 nodes. Besides that, one of the original nodes no longer exists, so the cluster now looks as follows: node1, node3, node4, node5, node6.

How to properly restore the snapshot data into the changed cluster?
Am I right that the only way to do it in the mentioned case is to use sstableloader?

If it is true, how to initiate the restore process providing that snapshots are placed on backup server where Cassandra is not installed? Do I need to install sstableloader there or I can launch it remotely?

How fast sstableloader will restore the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to read upon the following:

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/using-the-cassandra-bulk-loader-updated

In short the sstable loader will be aware of the topology of the cluster to which you are pushing the data. So the data will in the end end up on the correct nodes.

If for some reason it might be more feasible for you to get the sstables over to the nodes. You just might put them to the correct folders, then run reload or restart ... and after that a cleanup, but compared to the sstable loader, it's just not as elegant.

Comment: In the case I described previously the number of nodes were changed from the moment when snapshot was made. 
So, is it ok to place node2 backup data on node5? Will nodetool cleanup spread the data accross needed nodes after that?

Comment: no cleanup will not spread it, cleanup is just to drop everything that is not for this node. If you want to spread the data, theoretically you would have to place the backup of every node and then run the cleanup. I would go with the sstable loader in your case, it will stream the backed up data to the correct nodes in the cluster. You could do this with the copy cleanup combo but it's just time/resource intensive.

Comment: I would to prefer to go with the way of placing snapshots back to data folders, if it is possible to do in the cluster where number of nodes or replication was changed over time.

Comment: yes it's possible, but you have to place the backup files on all the nodes and then run cleanup on every node. Also don't forget to run `nodetool refresh` before the cleanup so that the data gets registred at the node.

Comment: Thanks Marko. I just worry about the time needed to restore data via sstableloader, I read it's very time consuming operation.
Aside from that, I will need to automate this process and I doubt sstableloader will return enough state information to handle fails that might occur during restore.